# gcc behavior when compiling a c recursive function with const parameters

Tags: c, recursion, gcc, parameters, constants

Given the following function:

```c
void rec_func(int a, int b, const int c) {
    /*
        flow control and stuff here
    */
    rec_func(a - 1, b, c);
}
```

Will gcc understand that c is the same constant value for all the recursive calls and then will use the same variable for all the calls, or it will copy the value of c to a new c variable each call?

The same question for b, even if not marked with const, will gcc understand that is implicitly const?

**Edit1:**
The question is made from an optimization perspective

**Edit2:**
By "implicitly const" I do not mean some keyword. I mean, a variable not tagged with the const modifier whose value will never change once initialized.

Comment: The answer is the same, whether it involves recursion or not

Comment: "implicitly const" is not a thing!  If it's const, the compiler won't let you change it; if it's not, you can.

Comment: What's not clear is your motivation for the question.

Comment: gcc's optimizer will convert this recursive call into a loop.

Comment: @EddInglis: “Implicitly const” is a thing; compilers generally are able to recognize some, perhaps many, invariants and optimize accordingly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I guess my point was that "implicitly const" isn't something the compiler could "understand" in the same way it could if something was *explicitly* const.  Undoubtedly, it can see that the code does not change a value, but I would argue that's semantically different.  I'm not sure it matters much to the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will gcc understand that c is the same constant value for all the recursive calls and then will use the same variable for all the calls, or it will copy the value of c to a new c variable each call?

In this particular case, gcc sees that the values are never used in a sensible way.  On x64, `gcc -Os -S file.c` generates the following assembly code (`file.s`, snipped irrelevant parts for brevity):

```
rec_func:
.L2:
    jmp .L2
```

Thus you should use some more sensible example.  gcc will try to transform recursive calls to loops like for

```c
int rec_func (int a, int b, const int c)
{
    return a == b
        ? c + a
        : 1 - rec_func (a - c, b, c);
}
```

again compiled with `-Os` (compiling for speed will not use recursion either, of course)

```
rec_func:
    movl    $1, %ecx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L3:
    cmpl    %esi, %edi
    je  .L5
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    subl    %edx, %edi
    negl    %ecx
    jmp .L3
.L5:
    addl    %edx, %edi
    imull   %ecx, %edi
    addl    %edi, %eax
    ret
```

No call / jump to `rec_func` anywhere.  Even with `c + 1` as 3rd argument, the generated code is only  one instructions longer.

> will gcc understand that is implicitly const?

Yes. As for the `const` in `const c`, this does not change anything; any real-world compiler suitable for practical purposes will determine on its own that `c` will never be changed.   The the present case `const` is just a reminder for you that `c` is read-only and you won't change it.

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is that you're coming at this from an optimization perspective.

If that's the case:

1. Don't worry about it; the compiler is much smarter than you* and will do a good job.
2. Recursion is rarely 'optimal' performance-wise.

If you don't try to alter `b` or `c` in your control logic, the compiler *might* do something clever, but passing around an `int` is not likely to be a big problem.  If you were passing around a giant structure, then you might consider using a pointer or reference instead.

Anyway, you can see what GCC is going to do with the amazing [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Fkfdw6) tool.

But as I said in my comment, it's not clear what the motivation for your question is, so I might be far wide of the mark with my answer.

[*] Not *you* specifically!

Comment: Aside: compilers often pass the first few parameters in registers, so there would be no need to copy them between calls anyway.

Comment: Very useful the godbolt tool! Thanks